# Symfony security access_control - multiple roles with AND operator

Tags: symfony, symfony5, symfony-security

Is it possible to assign required roles for route, where all of the roles are mandatory for granted access? Currently I have something like this:

```
security:
    access_control:
         - { path: ^/admin, roles:  [ROLE_EMAIL_VERIFIED, ROLE_ADMIN] }
         - { path: ^/user, roles:   [ROLE_EMAIL_VERIFIED, ROLE_USER] }
```

But even user, that has `ROLE_EMAIL_VERIFIED` have access to admin, because it's "`ROLE_EMAIL_VERIFIED` **or** `ROLE_ADMIN`" not **'and'**.

I found out about `allow_if` with usage of `has_role()`, but this was in Symfony 2 and in Symfony 5.4 this is not working (the function does not exist).

Comment: `allow_if` still exists and you can use an expression voter for that (see: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_control.html#securing-by-an-expression). But whenever logic gets more complicated, I usually add a voter on my controller or my controller's actions.

Comment: @JulienB. I meant the has_role function in allow_if does not exist anymore.
Yes, that would work, but I would have to write that to every controller (there are many of them) and make sure I don't forget to add that somewhere. So that's why I was looking for elegant solution in access_control that would solve it once and for all.

Comment: Symfony 6 ( probably same for 5.4 ): - { path: ^/admin, allow_if: "user and user.hasRole('ROLE_EMAIL_VERIFIED') and user.hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" }